# SpaCy - displaCy won't run after cancelling permissions

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spacy

When I ran SpaCy's displaCy.serve for the very first time a window popped up asking for permissions. Since this was unexpected I hit cancel. Not sure if the pop-up was related to Windows 10 or other software. Now when I execute displacy.serve it appears to be waiting for something, i.e. in jupyter notebook the cell doesn't finish executing and I can't proceed to rendering.

```
options = {'compact': True, 'bg': '#09a3d5', 'color': 'white', 'font': 'Source Sans Pro', 'notebook': True}
displacy.serve(doc, style='dep',  options=options)
```

> ```
> Serving on port 5000...
> Using the 'dep' visualizer
> ```

How can I set permissions to render with displaCy? Changing the port number and disabling the firewall did not help.

Comment: Did the notification come from your browser or your operating system? And are you running some kind of firewall? I assume this was probably about allowing the process to start a server on a specific localhost port. By the way, if you're in a Jupyter notebook, you should be able to use `display.render` with `jupyter=True` instead, which will call into Jupyter's HTML rendering methods and won't start a web server ([see here for details](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#jupyter)).

Comment: Apparently in Jupyter notebook I don't need to run displacy.serve. I can proceed directly to rendering with option `jupyter=True`. Thanks @InesMontani for putting me on the right track.